# Querying two schemas with populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So I have two schemas, one PoemRegistrations and the other CompetitionResults I want to render both forms in one page.

As I'm rendering most of the PoemRegistrations fields and one of the CompetitionResults I have attempted to populate the PoemRegistrations to pull in the data from the CompetitionResults winnersName field but I'm having some issues.

Here is what I have tried so far.

schema

```
winnersName: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompetitionResults' }],
```

and in the route I am currently trying

```
router.get('/dashboard/all-poems', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  PoemRegistrations.find({}).
  populate('winnersName').
  exec(function(err, poemRegistrations) {
    res.render('dashboard/all-poems.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'All Poems',
      poemRegistrations: poemRegistrations
    });
  });
});
```

I want to be able to render the winnersName ideally by doing

```
{{#each poemRegistrations}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{winnersName}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

#### What I want

I want to be able to pull in one field from another schema pull it from one schema into another and render to a page.

I can pull in the PoemRegistration fields with no issues I'm just trying to get the winnersName to render.

Any help here would be great.

#### Edit 1

schema [poem registrations]

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useMongoClient: true });
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pol-development', { useMongoClient: true });
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been established");
});

var PoemRegistrationsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  schoolName: String,
  competitionDate: String,

  // Poem 1
  poem1AuthorName: String,
  poem1Title: String,
  poem1Url: String,
  poem1AnthologyUrl: String,
  poem1LinesCheck: Boolean,
  poem1CenturyCheck: Boolean,
  poem1FreeCheck: Boolean,

  // Poem 2
  poem2AuthorName: String,
  poem2Title: String,
  poem2Url: String,
  poem2AnthologyUrl: String,
  poem2LinesCheck: Boolean,
  poem2CenturyCheck: Boolean,
  poem2FreeCheck: Boolean,

  // Poem 3
  poem3AuthorName: String,
  poem3Title: String,
  poem3Url: String,
  poem3AnthologyUrl: String,
  poem3LinesCheck: Boolean,
  poem3CenturyCheck: Boolean,
  poem3FreeCheck: Boolean,

  winnersName: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompetitionResults' }],

  // admin fields
  poemRegistrationRequiredDocuments: Boolean
});

var PoemRegistrations = module.exports = mongoose.model('PoemRegistrations', PoemRegistrationsSchema);
```

schema [competition results]

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useMongoClient: true });
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pol-development', { useMongoClient: true });
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been established");
});

var CompetitionResultsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  schoolName: String,
  winnersName: String,
  winnersGrade: String,
  winnersAddress: String,
  winnersCity: String,
  winnersZip: String,
  competitionDate: String,
  winnersTelephone: String,
  winnersParentName: String,
  winnersParentTelephone: String,
  winnersTShirtSize: String,
  winnersAccommodation: Boolean,
  winnersAccommodationComments: String,

  // admin fields
  winnersAttendedRehersal: Boolean,
  winnersAttendedMainCompetition: Boolean,
  winnersReleaseForm: Boolean,

  runnerUpsName: String,
  runnerUpsGrade: String,
  runnerUpsAddress: String,
  runnerUpsCity: String,
  runnerUpsZip: String,
  runnerUpsTelephone: String,
  runnerUpsParentName: String,
  runnerUpsParentTelephone: String,
  runnerUpsTShirtSize: String,
  runnerUpsAccommodation: Boolean,
  runnerUpsAccommodationComments: String,

  // admin comments
  runnerUpsAttendedRehersal: Boolean,
  runnerUpsAttendedMainCompetition: Boolean,
  runnerUpsReleaseForm: Boolean
});

var CompetitionResults = module.exports = mongoose.model('CompetitionResults', CompetitionResultsSchema);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `CompetitionResults` schema definition? It might be a matter of just referencing the field as `<td>{{winnersName[0].name}}</td>`

Comment: @chridam I've added both schema files to the questions

Comment: Thanks for the edit. A follow-up question with regards to the schema design, why making `winnersName` an array embedded documents from the `CompetitionResults` model? Are you expecting multiple winners per poem or a single winner? If it's the latter then I would recommend modifying your schema to just allow a single document rather than an array i.e. `winnersName: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompetitionResults' },`, displaying the populated document in the template as `<td>{{winnersName.winnersName}}</td>`. If you can't modify then `<td>{{winnersName[0].winnersName}}</td>`

Comment: @chridam There is a single winner yes, so I have tried this and the field data isn't rendering. So the `CompetitionResults` has been filled out and a winnersName is filled but I want that data to also pass into the `PoemRegistrations` so I can render it.

Comment: @chridam Can you still help on this?

Comment: If you stick in a `console.log(poemRegistrations)` just before `res.render('dashboard/all-poems.hbs', { .. }` what is logged?

Comment: @chridam Ok here's what I'm getting https://gist.github.com/benbagley/8df5cc651d5034e40cceb30dca72d41b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165061/discussion-between-chridam-and-b-j-b).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to re-design your schemas as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), 
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var poemSchema = Schema({
    authorName: String,
    title: String,
    url: String,
    anthologyUrl: String,
    linesCheck: Boolean,
    centuryCheck: Boolean,
    freeCheck: Boolean
});

var competitionResultSchema = Schema({
    schoolName: String,
    name: String,
    grade: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    zip: String,
    competitionDate: String,
    telephone: String,
    parentName: String,
    parentTelephone: String,
    tShirtSize: String,
    accommodation: Boolean,
    accommodationComments: String,

    // admin fields
    attendedRehersal: Boolean,
    attendedMainCompetition: Boolean,
    releaseForm: Boolean,
});


var poemRegistrationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    schoolName: String,
    competitionDate: String,

    // poems fields
    poems: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poem' }],

    // competition results fields
    winner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompetitionResult' },
    runnerUp: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompetitionResult' },

    // admin fields
    poemRegistrationRequiredDocuments: Boolean
});


var CompetitionResults = mongoose.model('CompetitionResult', competitionResultSchema);
var Poem  = mongoose.model('Poem', poemSchema); 
var PoemRegistration = mongoose.model('PoemRegistration', poemRegistrationSchema);
```

---

When you create the `poemRegistration` data, you also need the `poems`, `winner` and `runnerUp` data. For example, when you create the 3 poems using the async library's [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) workflow:

```
var  workflowPipeline = [
    function(callback) {
        Poem.insertMany([
            {
                authorName: "author1",
                title: "foo1",
                url: "foo/bar",
                anthologyUrl: "foo/bar",
                linesCheck: false,
                centuryCheck: false,
                freeCheck: false        
            },
            {
                authorName: "author2",
                title: "foo2",
                url: "foo/bar2",
                anthologyUrl: "foo/bar2",
                linesCheck: false,
                centuryCheck: false,
                freeCheck: false        
            },
            {
                authorName: "author3",
                title: "foo3",
                url: "foo/bar3",
                anthologyUrl: "foo/bar3",
                linesCheck: false,
                centuryCheck: false,
                freeCheck: false        
            }
        ], function(err, poems) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                } else {
                    callback(null, poems);
                }
        });    
    },
    function(poems, callback) {
        var winner = new CompetitionResult({ schoolName: 'School 1', name: 'Result 1' });
        var runnerUp = new CompetitionResult({ schoolName: 'School 2', name: 'Result 2' });
        callback(null, { poems: poems, winner: winner, runnerUp: runnerUp });
    },
    function(data, callback) {
        var registration = new PoemRegistration({
            schoolName: 'School 3',
            competitionDate: "2018-02-14",
            poems: data.poems.map(p => p._id),
            winner: data.winner._id,
            runnerUp: data.runnerUp._id
        });

        registration.save(function(err, reg){
            if (err) return callback(err, null);
            callback(null, reg);
        });
    }
];

async.waterfall(workflowPipeline, function (err, result) {
    // result is the new poem registration
});
```